# O'Neill's differential geometry: typo in formula for partial derivative?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, derivatives

I am working through Barrett O'Neill's Elementary Differential Geometry and I'm mildly confused. Exercise 3 in section 4.3 ask you to verify that $$\mathbf{y}_{u}=\mathbf{x}_{u}\frac{\partial \bar{u}}{\partial u}+\mathbf{x}_{v}\frac{\partial \bar{v}}{\partial u} $$ with a similar equation for $\mathbf{y}_{v}$. I have that $\mathbf{y}(u,v)=\mathbf{x}(\bar{u},\bar{v})$. I thought this was a typo, however this same notation appears in the next section as is. Any and all help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what there is to verify: Isn't this just taking the partial derivative wrt $u$ and $v$ respectively?

Comment: i thought it should be $\mathbf{x}_\bar{u}$ instead of just $u$ and similarly for $v$

Comment: @RudytheReindeer

Comment: Yes, correct, and that is what is written there, no? Can you tell me what the partial derivative of $y$ is with respect to $u$?

Comment: @RudytheReindeer, What is written has $\mathbf{x}$ being derived by $u$ and not $\bar{u}$. $$\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{x}_{\bar{u}}\frac{\partial\bar{u}}{\partial u} +\mathbf{x}_\bar{v}\frac{\partial \bar{v}}{\partial u}$$ I believe the source of my confusion is the notation. Why is it acceptable to just write $\mathbf{x}_{u}$ and not $\mathbf{x}_{\bar{u}}$?

Comment: Oh right, I'm sorry I don't have the book and I didn't notice the subscript was missing a bar. To me this looks like a rather blatant typo. Doing some googling for errata for this book it turned out that this book is "riddled with typos" (not my own words). I'm curious to see what others here will make of it.

Comment: You're correct. It is a typo and there should be subscripts of $\bar u$ and $\bar v$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Well, well. And I was going to offer a bounty on this if no one answered it. : ) I think it is quite odd though that the author would consistently make the same typo throughout the book.

Comment: Some of us authors pay more attention to detail than others. I doubt this typo shows up too often. The typesetters messed up the chain rule ... But how often does he really write such an equation?

Comment: @TedShifrin O'Neill uses this same notation 2 pages later while proving that the exterior derivative of a one form is unique over the intersection of coordinate patches. The continued use of this terrible notation is what caused me to ask the question. I thought maybe I wasn't on the inside loop with you hip geometers :)

Comment: @Daniel: Very sloppy typesetting/proofreading. O'Neill's book predates LaTeX by a good long while. ... But if you find any significant typos in my differential geometry notes, please do let me know! :)

Comment: @TedShifrin Well your errata for G&P has saved me from asking a few silly questions before this. For that I'm thankful for. As for your notes, I haven't found one yet, but I'm sure they are there; I'll keep looking.